# Bootstrap 4 nav pills are not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

```html
     <!-- Bootstrap pills -->
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active">
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="driver-details-tab">Driver Details</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#erer">Register Driver</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
          <div class="container-fluid drivers-main tab-pane active" id="driver-details-tab" role="tabpanel">
 <div class="tab-pane" id="register-driver-tab" role="tabpanel">
              asdsdd
          </div>
                      <div class="container-fluid drivers-main tab-pane active" id="erer" role="tabpanel">
 <div class="tab-pane" id="register-driver-tab" role="tabpanel">
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
          </div>
  </div>
```

Hello, I'm using nav-pills in bootstrap but for some reason it is not working properly, Please take a look at the code above, I haven't included bootstrap in the above fiddle

Comment: Have you bothered to compare your code to the bootstrap doc version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use something like this for the pills:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#driver-details-tab">Driver Details</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#erer">Register Driver</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note the classes that I've added.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#driver-details-tab">Driver Details</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#erer">Register Driver</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">        
      <div class="container-fluid drivers-main tab-pane active" id="driver-details-tab" role="tabpanel">
          asdsdd
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid drivers-main tab-pane active" id="erer" role="tabpanel"> fff</div>
    </div>
```

Check that out! Don't forget to include the # sign before the id name in href as well!

Answer (score 1):

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/4ukwcf6x/)**

Bootstrap 3 or 4

Once CSS is not working, kindly use the JavaScript to navigate. (If only CSS doesn't work)

```
<!-- Bootstrap pills -->
<ul class="nav flex-column" id="v-pills-tab">
<li class="active">
<a data-toggle="pill" href="driver-details-tab">Driver Details</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-toggle="pill" href="#erer">Register Driver</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="container-fluid drivers-main tab-pane active" id="driver-details-tab" role="tabpanel">
<div class="tab-pane" id="register-driver-tab" role="tabpanel">
asdsdd
</div>
<div class="container-fluid drivers-main tab-pane active" id="erer" role="tabpanel">
<div class="tab-pane" id="register-driver-tab" role="tabpanel">
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
</div>
</div>

<script>
$('#v-pills-tab a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show')
})

</script>
```